# Is GAE optimized for database-heavy applications?

Tags: database, google-app-engine, optimization, nosql

I'm writing a very limited-purpose web application that stores about 10-20k user-submitted articles (typically 500-700 words). At any time, any user should be able to perform searches on tags and keywords, edit any part of any article (metadata, text, or tags), or download a copy of the entire database that is recent up-to-the-hour. (It can be from a cache as long as it is updated hourly.) Activity tends to happen in a few unpredictable spikes over a day (wherein many users download the entire database simultaneously requiring 100% availability and fast downloads) and itermittent weeks of low activity. This usage pattern is set in stone.

Is GAE a wise choice for this application? It appeals to me for its low cost (hopefully free), elasticity of scale, and professional management of most of the stack. I like the idea of an app engine as an alternative to a host. However, the excessive limitations and quotas on all manner of datastore usage concern me, as does the trade-off between strong and eventual consistency imposed by the datastore's distributed architecture.

Is there a way to fit this application into GAE? Should I use the ndb API instead of the plain datastore API? Or are the requirements so data-intensive that GAE is more expensive than hosts like Webfaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't require full text search on the articles (which is currently still marked as experimental and [limited to ~1000 queries per day](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview#Quotas)), your usage scenario sounds like it would fit just fine in App Engine.

> stores about 10-20k user-submitted articles (typically 500-700 words)

Maximum entity size in App Engine is [1 MB](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/overview#Quotas_and_Limits), so as long as the total size of the article is lower than that, it should not be a problem. Also, the cost for reading data in is not tied to the size of the entity but to the number of entities being read.

> At any time, any user should be able to perform searches on tags and keywords.

Again, as long as the search on the tags and keywords are not full text searches, App Engine's [datastore queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries) could handle these kind of searches efficiently. If you want to search on both tags and keywords at the same time, you would need to build a [composite index](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection#Advanced_Search) for both fields. This could [increase your write cost](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing#Billable_Resource_Unit_Costs).

> download a copy of the entire database that is recent up-to-the-hour.

You could use [cron/scheduled task](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron) to schedule a hourly dump to the blobstore. The cron could be targeted to a backend instance if your dump takes more than 60 seconds to be finished. Do remember that with each dump, you would need to read all entities in the database, and this means 10-20k read ops per hour. You could add a timestamp field to your entity, and have your dump servlet query for anything newer than the last dump instead to save up read ops.

> Activity tends to happen in a few unpredictable spikes over a day (wherein many users download the entire database simultaneously requiring 100% availability and fast downloads) and itermittent weeks of low activity.

This is where GAE shines, you could have very efficient instance usages with GAE in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your application is particularly "database-heavy". 
500-700 words is only a few KB of data.

I think GAE is a good fit.

You could store each article as a textproperty on an entity, with tags in a listproperty. For searching text you could use the search service https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/  (which currently has quota limits).

Not 100% sure about downloading all the data, but I think you could store all the data in the blobstore (possibly as pdf?) and then allow users to download that blob.

I would choose NDB over regular datastore, mostly for the built-in async functionality and caching.

Regarding staying below quota, it depends on how many people are accessing the site and how much data they download/upload.